# char array in structs - why does strlen() return the correct value here?

Tags: c, initialization

I have a simple program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int numberOfDays;
    char name[10];
} Month;


int main(void) 
{
    const Month months[12] = { 
        { 31, {'J', 'a', 'n'} },
        { 28, {'F', 'e', 'b'} }
    };

    printf("%zu\n", strlen(months[0].name));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(months[0].name));

    printf("%zu\n", strlen(months[1].name));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(months[1].name));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is like this:

```
3
10
3
10
```

I understand why `sizeof(months[i].name)` prints 10, but why does `strlen` return the correct value in this case?

My thought was, that `strlen` counts until the first `'\0'`, but the `char name[3]` array is not null terminated. From my understanding this should be undefined behaviour? Does it only work by accident?

I'm wondering what the memory layout is in the above `months[12]` array.

Comment: WRONG. This is not UB. The remainder of the struct is initialized to zeros.

Comment: Sorry its my bad guys. In the struct in wrote `char name[10]` but in the question i spoke about  `char name[3]`. Both work though, that is what wonders me.

Comment: @Max Please do not edit question in a way that makes the already provided answer(s) look out of context. Thank you.

Comment: It made more sense before you edited - the `sizeof` results.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR Answer:** No, this is well-defined behaviour.

**Explanation:** As per the `C11` standard document, chapter 6.7.9, initalization,

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

In your case, you have a `char` array of `10` elements

```
 char name[10];
```

and you've supplied initializer for only 3 elements, like

```
{ 31, {'J', 'a', 'n'} },
```

So, the rest of the elements in `name` is initialized to `0` or `'\0'`. So, in this case, `strlen()` returns the correct result.

**Note:** Please do not rely on this *method* for null-termination of *strings*. In case, you're supplying the exact number of elements as initalizer, there will be no null-termination.

---

EDIT:

In case the `name` definition is changed to `char name[3]` and initialized with three `char`s, then , as per the note above, usage of `strlen()` (and family) will be  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as it will overrun the allocated memory area in search of terminating null.

Comment: OK, that makes sende. What I was wondering … even if I change the declaration to `char name[3]` it still works without segfault.

Comment: In that case you *are* lucky, as there only "happens" to be a terminating 0.

Comment: @Max Please see the note below my answer. :-)

Comment: @WeatherVane not lucky; it's just that some bytes of the small integers happen to be 0, and also (I think) Sourav's brace initialization rule would fill the remaining 10 months in the array with 0. So strlen() will work but return unexpected lengths.

Comment: @PeterSchneider that was what I meant by "lucky". The terminating 0 is not part of the array[3]: it wasn't by design, it was by chance.

Comment: @PeterSchneider OP changed the code, if that is what you're worried about.

Comment: @WeatherVane The program runs deterministically; so it was chance all along, or not at all ;-).

Comment: I'm always wondering how fast people here which answers questions in C know about standard and which section etc. Curious, do you know the standard to such an extent? Pretty impressive.

Comment: @Max it is not really as vast as you may think. somewhat realted to [Pareto Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle). ;-)

Comment: Haha, that makes me actually curious, I will have a look at it myself. I'm learning C for my sideprojects, so it can only be beneficial. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I thought that about the high bytes of the integers too, but check again.  There's a padding byte, probably right after the `char[3]`.  And I bet it's filled with zeros.  For your second comment, you _say_ it runs deterministically, but when it comes to UB that's not an accurrate claim.

Comment: You can't even be sure of null-termination when using a string literal, as C allows the literal to be an exact fit. (C++ requires that there be room for the null terminator.)

Comment: @MooingDuck Good observation with the padding byte. It will usually be there and will lead to the correct length. Nice. New defensive programming patten: Give char arrays odd lengths ;-). -- UB: Not sure. I cannot find a wording that restricts `strlen()` to memory declared as char (as long as the general requirement is met that the memory belongs to some object, which it does). Accessing arbitrary types through char pointers is allowed, iirc. Null initialization of months Mar-Dec guarantees `strlen()` to not run off.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: `strlen` isn't restricted as such, but I'm not sure about the UB involved with reading padding bytes is.  I know in some cases it's defined, but I think in some cases it's UB.  I tend to avoid it in all cases.

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that your months are indeed nul-terminated. If you have an array with 10 elements, and have an initialiser for 3 elements, then the rest is filled with 0's. If you had a month with 11 characters, the compiler would tell you. If you had a month with 10 characters, you would be in trouble because there would be no nul-termination, and the compiler wouldn't tell you.

Answer (score 4):

When you partially initialise the `struct`, those parts not specifically initialised are set to 0.

So the strings do have a terminating 0 and so `strlen()` returns the correct value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int i;
    char s[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d ", s[i]);
    printf("\n%d\n", strlen(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
97 98 99 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3
```